# Calling a div and content in php?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

Is there a code that i can place in the header that will call a certain div and the content i place inside it for every custom post type i have, Somthething like this.

```
 <?php if (is_post_type('pretty-little-liars') ) {echo '<div id="headerimg"><img src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/liars.png"></div>'; } ?>
```

I know that the code above doesn't work, but is there a way that i can call something like that for each post type i have, i will be placing this code in the header.

Also if anyone does have the solution could you please tell me where do i add a second line to the code that repeats the first line but with a different post type name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will only work in the loop, but what you can do outside of the loop is use

```
<?php
if (get_post_type() == 'pretty-little-liars') {
echo '<div id="headerimg"><img src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/liars.png"></div>'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you that works.....but how do i add a second line

Comment: When i create a second one it shows in the home page :(